# What is ADS in sniping?

Tags: terminology, first-person-shooter

I feel a tad stupid. I play as a sniper in almost any FPS I play, but I recently came across this term (ADS). What does it mean? What is its significance?

Comment: I read that as "AIDS" at first and was like "what?!"

Comment: @nyuszika7h lol.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ADS stands for Aim(ing) down sights. It's (in my opinion) a spectacularly stupid acronym. It refers to using iron sights or a scope, as opposed to hip firing.

Comment: Thanks. This was too simple to figure out myself apparently.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 it took me a minute the first time I encountered it, but context in that case helped a lot.  A sniper probably doesn't think about it much, in that ADS is the "normal" state for a sniper (as opposed to "no-scoping"), but for other roles the decision of whether or not to take the time to pull up the scope (especially in games that penalize switching from sprint to ADS) is a tough one, especially with perks or equipment that affect one state or the other exclusively muddying up the waters.

Comment: @gatherer818 definitely. I just never had a "formal" name for it